# App slowness after using UIView Animations

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, ios7, xcode5

So I have an App of which I animate some UI Elements as soon as the app opens. These animations are done using simple UIView Animations. Below is a sample of the viewDidLoad portion

```
    //animate settings in the frame
    CGRect settingsFrame = settingsView.frame;
    settingsFrame.origin.x = -104;
    settingsFrame.origin.y = 457;
    settingsView.frame = settingsFrame;

    //animate about in the frame
    CGRect aboutFrame = aboutView.frame;
    aboutFrame.origin.x = -104;
    aboutFrame.origin.y = 457;
    aboutView.frame = aboutFrame;
```

And here is a the corresponding method portion that is called.

```
CGRect settingsFrame = settingsView.frame;
settingsFrame.origin.x = 0; // new x coordinate
settingsFrame.origin.y = 457; // new y coordinate
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
settingsView.frame = settingsFrame;

CGRect aboutFrame = aboutView.frame;
aboutFrame.origin.x = 104; // new x coordinate
aboutFrame.origin.y = 457; // new y coordinate
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
aboutView.frame = aboutFrame;
```

There are 4 more matching sets of code to finish out the animation. My problem is, whenever the viewDidLoad portion is enabled (not commented out) it slows down the other transitions to xib's in my App. Do you guys have any idea how I can keep these animations but not have the slow transitions?

In addition to that, I should say this is being developed on iOS 7 and Xcode 5 Developer Preview, so I'm not ruling out a bug...

Comment: If they both have the same duration and the same animation curve why are you doing them in separate animation 'blocks'?

Comment: Because each block goes to a slightly different place. I can not get it to function correctly without each block. Do you know of a way to get it to work?

Comment: Setup your initial locations for everything.  Then use `UIView animate: with...` to do the animating.  If you are talking about different points in code then use multiple animation blocks (but they may work concurrently in the background and thereby cause "slowness").  In my experience doing all concurrent animations in a single animation call works the smoothest, if you can find a way of doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add commitAnimations at the end of the animation block...
Do below, you problem will be fixed.

```
CGRect settingsFrame = settingsView.frame;
settingsFrame.origin.x = 0; // new x coordinate
settingsFrame.origin.y = 457; // new y coordinate
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
settingsView.frame = settingsFrame;
**[UIView commitAnimations];**

CGRect aboutFrame = aboutView.frame;
aboutFrame.origin.x = 104; // new x coordinate
aboutFrame.origin.y = 457; // new y coordinate
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
aboutView.frame = aboutFrame;
**[UIView commitAnimations];**
```